# Keep UIView always on top throughout the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow

I want to create a global navigation view in my iphone app (like ios notification view), which will be shown on swipe down from any screen of the app. I have added a subview `UIViewController.View` on `UIWindow` to achieve this along with `UISwipeGesture` on the `UIWindow` and it is working as somewhat expected. The view is shown whenever and wherever in the app swipe gesture is detected.

The problem is that it appears when some other gestures are performed. I want to set the effect of the swipe for global menu on top part of the screen only. What can I try for this?

Answer (score 0):

Set your gesture recognizer's delegate and implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` to detect only touches on top part of the screen:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.window];
  BOOL touchedOnTop = location.y < 60;
  return touchedOnTop;
}
```

I guess you have already done that but you should also set direction of the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown`.

Some extra work will be needed if your app supports multiple interface orientations.